# query to sum value array object on postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table slow with column default and type column is text
and the value on the bellow:

```
{"default":[{"value_1": 100, "value_2": 0.1},{"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.2}], "non_default":[{"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.1}, {"value_1": 100, "value_2": 0.1}]}
```

and how to sum for each of default -> value_1 ?

I have tried this it's result null

```
select sum(cast(additional ::json-> 'default' ::text->> 'value_1' as integer)) as sum_default from "slow" where id = 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your JSON value is an object containing an array, We can try to use `json_array_elements` function to get array by key is `default`

```
select SUM((v.val->>'value_1')::INT)
from "slow" t1
cross join lateral json_array_elements(t1.additional::json-> 'default') as v(val)
where id = 'id'
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=22b72ff510d018aa19b8f89f2ae7f5d2)

Comment: the column type addtional is 'text'

and I tried the query resulting 
```
ERROR: cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array
```

Comment: now it's work
modified on "slow" t1 -> "slow"
json_array_elements(t1.additional::json) -> json_array_elements(additional::json)

I don't know why ?
maybe u can tell me why?

Comment: It is just an alias name for that, that might be worked alias name  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ac758f388f38a2b7e5e1688570bd1b1e

Comment: can I ask again ?, it's how to set ::json -> 'default' to 'non_default" base on other column.
Example I have column -> name and value -> 'john' and other column -> name_adds and the value -> 'john'. Both of column name and name_adds can be diffrent value. If name and name_adds is same I want to (additional::json->'default') and if it not same I want to (additional::json->'non_default').  How I can do that ????